# Get a specific data from specific <script type="text/javascript">

Tags: python, regex

I have a html page with multiple javascript tags. The problem that I want to extract data  from specific tag:

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">

    $j(document).ready(function() {

        if (!($j.cookie("ios"))) {
            new $c.free.widgets.FreeAdvDialog().open();
            $j.cookie("ios", "seen", { path: '/', expires: 10000});
        };

        ajax_keys = ["d24349f205e3deb7f1015f42d3a14da7205b62e4", "0ae78c4797d47745ebd44e2754367da10c6f56a4", "567b2bfb6fd1aee784115da54e5e116a280ee225", "fc5cd251be46ff101c471553d52c07bf08c9aa65"];
        var is_dm = false;

        /* async chart loader */
        var chart = new $c.free.widgets.Chart({
            target: $j('#graph'),
            width: 990,
            height: 275,
            site: "911.com",
            source_panel: 'us'
        });

        var chart_view = new $c.free.widgets.ChartView({
            chart: chart,
            csv_button: 'csv-export',
            save_button: 'graph-image',
            embed_button: 'embed-graph',
            key: ajax_keys[1]
        });
        chart_view.render();

        /* zoom info initialization */
        var zoom_info = new $c.free.widgets.ZoomInfo({
            site: "911.com",
            el: '#zoominfo',
            key: ajax_keys[3]
        });
        zoom_info.load();


        /* compete numbers initialization */
        var compete_numbers = new $c.free.widgets.CompeteNumbers({
            site: "911.com",
            key: ajax_keys[0],
            el: '#compete_numbers'
        });
        compete_numbers.load();

        /* DM Marketing widget init */
        new $c.free.widgets.DMSignupMessage({
            is_dm: is_dm,
            compete_numbers: compete_numbers
        });

        /* personalization initialization */


            var logged_in_as = null;


        var d = {
          site_name: "911.com",
          logged_in_as: logged_in_as,
          current_source_panel: {"display_abbreviation": "us", "panel_name": "us", "image_url": "http://media.compete.com/site_media/images/icons/flag_us.gif", "id": 1, "display_name": "United States"}
        };

        var auth_model = new $c.free.widgets.FreeLoginModel(d);
        var links_opts = { model: auth_model };
        var links_view = new $c.free.widgets.FreeAccountLinksView(links_opts);

        var sites_view = new $c.free.widgets.FollowSiteButtonView(links_opts);
        var manage_view = new $c.free.widgets.ManageSitesListButtonView(links_opts);

        var sites = new $c.free.widgets.SimilarSitesCollection([], {
            site: "911.com",
            source_panel: 'us',
            key: ajax_keys[2],
            auth: auth_model
        });
        var graph = new $c.free.widgets.BarGraph({
            el: $j('#similar-sites'),
            collection: sites
        });

        // tell KISSMetrics where we are
        // also identify user so KM console can refer to them by email
        if(logged_in_as != null) {
            _kmq.push(['identify', logged_in_as]);
        }
        _kmq.push(['record', 'Viewed Free Site Analytics Report (M)']);
    });
```

...

How can I get **ajax_keys** (i.e. "d24349f205e3deb7f1015f42d3a14da7205b62e4") from specific  tag of the page?

p.s. i tried to use regular expressions in python script but i can't retrieve necessary element from  tag.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a library like BeautifulSoup you can fetch the specific script tag, and then use a regex on the contents of the tag instead of the entire document.

That said, it looks like a regex will work assuming there is only the one `ajax_keys`:

```
import re

ajaxre = re.compile(r"^\s+ajax_keys = ([^;]+)", re.MULTILINE)
ajax_string = ajaxre.match(source).group(1)

# to get it as a python list
import json
ajax_keys = json.loads(ajax_string)
```

**Edit:** thanks @Karl Knechtel for json.loads

Comment: "careful doing this in general" - no excuses; you want `ast.literal_eval`. Or maybe even `json.loads`.

Comment: eval is evil.  Good call on json.loads, updating answer

Comment: Thanks! Another problem that i have multiple <script type="text/javascript"> tags without tag id. I tried smth. like this: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen('url').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
to_extract = soup.findAll('script')
for item in to_extract:
    item.extract() - that exactly print out data from all <script> tags of the page. How can I find specific tag if it doesn't have any id?

Comment: If you don't have any id but you know it's position you can use indexing.  EG. 3rd script tag `soup.findAll("script")[2]`, last script tag `soup.findAll("script")[-1]` and so on.

Comment: Finally i catch that! Thank you! One more question - what is (source) in ajaxre.match? is it source of parsed page or retrieved <script> tag?

Comment: Source is just the HTML as one big string (not split by lines) or the contents of the script tag.  The regex matches all lines that start with white space and then has `ajax_keys = `. As long as only one line of the html looks like that, you can just run it on the full page.  Otherwise, as long as only one line in the script tag looks like that, it'll work for the script text.

Comment: Also, just noticed I used `\w` instead of `\s` which I meant.  Fixed the code.

Comment: Interesting, what if ajax_keys change its value? So every time i should change ajax_string? @agoebel

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The code should match anything on the other side of the equals sign of `ajax_keys`.  If you are reloading the webpage from your code, yes you'd just rerun most of these lines. @alex-a

Comment: I mean, that i have the page i.e. http://example.com/search?q=u:test1.com. If i type another page http://example.com/search?q=u:test2.com i'll get another value of ajax_keys. So every time i should change source line ('ajaxre.match(**source**).group(1)') in ajax_string? @agoebel